# Python regex wrap digits in underscores and replace all other underscores with dots

Tags: python, regex

I would like to put all numbers in my strings into square brackets followed by a dot, which should essentially replace the underscores. All other underscores in the string should be replaced with dots.

What's the best way to go about this? I only need to remove the dot before `[`. 'fields' could be any string.

String:

```
fields_5_type_fields_1_name
```

Desired Output:

```
fields[5].type.fields[1].name
```

Current result:

```
fields.[5].type.fields.[1].name
```

Code:

```
i = re.sub(r"\d+", r"[\g<0>]", i)

i = re.sub(r"_", r".", i)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply `re.sub` twice:

```
import re
s = 'fields_5_type_fields_1_name'
new_s = re.sub('_\d+', lambda x:f'[{x.group()[1:]}]', re.sub('(?<=[a-z\d])_(?=[a-z])', '.', s))
```

Output:

```
'fields[5].type.fields[1].name'
```

This will also handle cases where an instance of index notation occurs without a subsequent `.`:

```
s = 'fields_5_type_fields_1'
print(re.sub('_\d+', lambda x:f'[{x.group()[1:]}]', re.sub('(?<=[a-z\d])_(?=[a-z])', '.', s)))
```

Output:

```
'fields[5].type.fields[1]'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an alternation `|` to match either an optional `_` followed by capturing 1+ digits in group 1, or match `_` ad check for the group value to do the right replacement.

```
import re

pattern = r"_?(\d+)|_"
i = "fields_5_type_fields_1_name"
res = re.sub(pattern, lambda x: f"[{x.group(1)}]" if x.group(1) else ".", i)
print(res)
```

Output

```
fields[5].type.fields[1].name
```

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/Ri6fK2)

Answer (score 1):

```
i = re.sub(r"\d+", r"[\g<0>]", i)  # Put brackets around numbers.
i = re.sub(r"_\[", r"[", i)        # Remove the underscore before brackets.
i = re.sub(r"_", r".", i)          # Replace the remaining underscores.
```

Answer (score 0):

You've almost done everything, just change the first line:

```
i = re.sub(r"_(\d+)_", r"[\g<1>].", txt)

i = re.sub(r"_", r".", i)
```